# Adding a link to a code with brackets escapes it automatically

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown

Recently while formatting a post, I noticed that the brackets in the code (formatted by using `code`) are getting escaped automatically, when we give a link to it.

Take this as a sample [`callMe(\[\])`](https://stackoverflow.com/). I just added a link to it by using the hyperlink button which is present above the post editing area. So after doing this, we have to manually remove the backslashes to make it as [`callMe([])`](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Steps to reproduce,

- Select the code and click the ***code
  sample*** button to make it look like `callMe([])`
- Give it a link by selecting the text `callMe([])` and press
  ***hyperlink button***.
- Now you will see this [`callMe(\[\])`](https://stackoverflow.com/)

It is not breaking anything even if i remove the backslashes manually, then why it is required? Or is there a reason behind escaping that?

FYI : `[]` is an empty array in javascript.