# Editor automatically adds backslashes to escape square brackets of text with square brackets

Tags: discussion, support, bug, editor, autocomplete

Selecting text containing square brackets and adding a link (<kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>) adds backslashes to escape the brackets in the text automatically. But the text is code and is surrounded by backticks, so it doesn't matter. The backslashes are rendered as-is.

I know that this is a duplicate of:

1. [Hyperlinking square brackets bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340178/hyperlinking-square-brackets-bug)
2. [Adding a link to a code with brackets escapes it automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319353/adding-a-link-to-a-code-with-brackets-escapes-it-automatically)
3. [Making backticked code, with square brackets a link, introduces redundant slashes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374768/making-backticked-code-with-square-brackets-a-link-introduces-redundant-slashe)

But the bug still exists. Please make it so that it escapes only square brackets that are not inside code blocks.

Comment: @Larnu, no, as it doesn't have an answer. It has not been fixed yet.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. The bug report already exists; we don't need another one.

Comment: @Larnu, why not retract the close vote and upvote instead so that they notice and fix it?

Comment: Because it's a duplicate. I might have previously already upvoted (one or more of) the duplicate(s); I see no need to post this again, when you've already found 3 reports for the problem.

Comment: @Larnu, okay, then; thought posting it again would bring the bug to notice. Everyone make sure you make the other posts active so that they receive attention. I've voted to close it too.

Comment: By that argument you should post a duplicate every day until it is fixed (and maybe it is never fixed regardless of how many duplicates you create). More duplicates does not mean more attention or higher priority. It just causes more work for other people, and in fact dilutes the community's ability to weigh in on how important something is, and spreads comments and answers across multiple pages making them harder to find and consolidate.